# Zabbix nodes hostnames on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, hostname, zabbix

On zabbix-server (GCE instance, which works with another instances in my projects) in log gettin this kind of error:

```
cannot send list of active checks to [<node-ip-address>]: host [<node-name>.c.<project-name>.internal] not found
```

Why it looks for instances over hostname, if it has an IP?

How can I solve this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an active Zabbix agent requests a list of active checks, it specifies its hostname (say, "linux01"). Zabbix server then checks its configuration to see whether there is a host named "linux01". If there is such a host, it sends a list of active checks for this host. If there is no such host, then Zabbix server replies with the error you are getting. So you should check that the hostname in the Zabbix agent configuration file matches the hostname in Zabbix server database.

Comment: So i can go two ways: (1) set that kind of hostnames in zabbix_agentd.conf on my instances (2) set that kind of hostnames in "hostname" attribute of my instances on zabbix-server web?

Comment: Yes, the hostname in zabbix_agentd.conf should match the host configuration in Zabbix frontend. Documentation at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd says the following regarding Hostname configuration parameter: "Required for active checks and must match hostname as configured on the server.".